# React Native Linking: Status of SMS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sms, deep-linking

When using Linking to send SMS, is there a way to check if the SMS is sent or cancelled?

Currently this is what my function looks like. But I want to be able to have different callbacks if SMS is sent or cancelled.

```
import { Linking, Platform } from 'react-native';

const sendSMS = async (phoneNumber, message) => {
  try {
    const separator = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '&' : '?';
    const url = `sms:${phoneNumber}${separator}body=${message}`;
    await Linking.openURL(url);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error while sending SMS message: ', err);
  }
};

export default sendSMS;
```